# Solutions to getting twitter bootstrap working with tag-it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, tag-it

If I add Tag-it to a twitter bootstrap project the field width keeps growing as I type in more values.  I'd need the field to stay the max width I specified using bootstrap classes.  This solution is close https://github.com/richardpoole/jquery-tagit/downloads, but wasn't built with the latest Tag-it so the type-ahead feature for tag-it seems to be missing.

Thoughts?